# how to add constraint of value check on a slick table column

Tags: slick

I have a requirement of adding column constraint on a table as follows:

alter table CH

```
add constraint CH_N_TYPE_CHK check (N_TYPE = 'bc' or N_TYPE = 'pub');
```

such that all values inserted to `CH.N_TYPE` should be either `bc` or `pub` only.

I want to use slick's table.ddl to create the tables.
I reckon it might involve Constraint class but it seems only support foreign key or index, I searched the code on slick or slick-test-kit but couldn't find any hint.
Is it feasible on on a slick table?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything related to check in the constraint usage, the only way that I find out was to use a enumeration in your column.

```
CH(tag:Tag) extends Table[CHRow]("ch") {
val nType: Column[NType.Value] = column[NType.Value]("N_TYPE")
implicit val enumMapper = MappedColumnType.base[NType.Value, String](_.toString(),  NType.withName(_))
.
.
.
}
```

And define your enumeration as follows 
    abstract class NType extends Enumeration {
      val BC = Value
      val PUB = Value
    }

With this you can only insert values BC or PUB int your column.
The code above follows the patterns for slick 2.0, but with some little modifications you can use it in slick 1.